# ¿Vistas en visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#

buenas tardes estuve revisando y no encuentro la forma de que aparezcan las llaves en las relaciones entre las tablas, si alguien sabe como por favor decirme.

link de la imagen:
https://subefotos.com/ver/?4eb6a2c2920a1c7e6212ecf5bbe1a003o.png

Comment: No se ve la imagen, lleva a un enlace roto.

Comment: ya hice la modificación

Comment: @Cpp procura por favor leer [ask] y proveer un [mcve] aqui en tu pregunta en lugar de mandar a enlaces externos

Comment: Envié un enlace externo debido a que en sí la página no me admitió la imagen, si es que no es visible la imagen por favor hazme saber.,